# Convert FAQ JSON file into RASA nlu and stories files

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I have a JSON file of 500+ FAQ that I want to use in RASA to make FAQ chatbot. This JSON file has a question and respective answer. I need to create nlu, stories and domain files in RASA. Is there any way to do it automatically? because manually will take so much time.

Comment: You just answered your own question: `Is there any way to do it automatically?`. Create a script that does just that.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do with the data you have. If you want to use it to train an NLU model, you (or somebody) will have to manually tag which intent each utterance belongs to. If you want to use it to train an NLG model, you could write a script to format your data into the relevant intents & responses, respectively (see https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/retrieval-actions/#training-data). 
As far as stories are concerned, you will need to write these manually, however, if you are using retrieval actions, these could turn out to be a lot simpler and fewer than you'd think.

I'd recommend checking out retrieval actions, as that sounds most relevant to your data.

Answer (score 1):

I elaborate a bit the @lahsuk comment and the @Melinda answer.

Suppose your JSON (`faq.json`) is something like this micro example:

```
[
  {
    "name":"1",
    "question":"question balbla 1",
    "answer":"answer blabla 1"
  },
  {
    "name":"2",
    "question":"question bla bla bla 2",
    "answer":"question bla bla 2"
  },
  {
    "name":"3",
    "question":"question blablabla 3",
    "answer":"answer blablabla 3"
  },
]
```

> BTW, I add explicitly the attribute `name` that's optional but useful
>   afterward. If you don't have a name you can use a sequential
>   incremental number (an id) to identify Q/A couple.

### **Step 1: data files script generation (mandatory/minimal)**

At first,  let's suppose to use [RASA Retrieval Actions](https://blog.rasa.com/response-retrieval-models/) to manage our faq. 
In this scenario we are going to add to our RASA model just a single intent named e.g. `faq`. We have to add a row in the domain.yml

```sh
intents:
  - faq
```

So, you must split JSON questions and answers, creating 2 kind of files from your `faq.json`:

1. `data/nlu.md`
2. `data/responses.md`

```sh
<!-- faq data/nlu.md: contains questions as intents -->
## intent: faq/1
- question balbla 1

## intent: faq/2
- question bla bla bla 2

## intent: faq/3
- question blablabla 3
```

```sh
<!-- faq data/responses.md: contains answers -->
## faq/1
* faq/1
  - answer blabla 1

## faq/2
* faq/2
  - question bla bla 2

## faq/3
* faq/3
  - answer blablabla 3
```

To do the task, you can create a script in any language of your choice, even in bash script, that take in input your JSOn and produce 2 file in described format.

> Minor note: identifying each question/answer pair with a numeric id is
>   possible but have drawbasks. It could be better to give a self-talking name to each pair.

### **Step 2: intents data "augmentation" (optional/improvement)**

The first step is the minimal requirement. But having just a question example as intent is not the best. The user could express a question in different ways. A good idea could be to explode the single question in nlu.md, giving some different examples. E.g.

```sh
<!-- faq data/nlu.md: many questions for the same answer -->
## intent: faq/1
- original question balbla 1
- another question example
- a third question example
```

## Digression: pros and cons using Retrieval responses

> You mentioned stories. In facts, the trivial approach for a faq is to
>   foresee single-turn question answers, without any contextual scope. 
>   Retrieval Actions are probably good solution to manage single-turn
>   "volleys".
>
> But, it could be smarter to foresee possible navigation in faq
>   knowledge base. By example, the bot could try to verify if the answer
>   to a question have been useful and maybe it could propose a deepen
>   subtopics related to the initial question.
>
> Here stories are great! But to create automatic stories from data, you
>   probably need to "tag" your question/answers in your input JSON and
>   avoid Retrieval Actions, preferring standard approach, having
>   separated intents and responses in your `domain.yml`. At least the compromise is to couple bot Retrieval Actions and "macro intents" to allow a knowledge navigation inside a dialog.
>
> [RASA Sara demo assistant](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa-demo/blob/master/data/core/faqs.md) contains interesting/complex stories as example of a smart faq assistance, using [Rasa Core
>   stories](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/stories/) "learn by example" dialogs. See also the article: [Integrate response retrieval models in assistants built with Rasa](https://blog.rasa.com/response-retrieval-models/)

Another Retrieval Responses minus is the lack of text formatting in answers, as I pointed out in [my RASA forum question](https://forum.rasa.com/t/response-selectors-error-responses-md-markdown-format-issue-questions-big-text-answers-faq-cr/27856).